# How can I get the timing value and see the function output when I use system.time() in R?

Tags: r

When I run my function inside of system.time(), it doesn't show the value of the output. In my case I'm writing files to disk with a function:

```
>system.time(lapply(some.long.character.string.of.inputs, SomeLongFunction))
user      system    elapsed 
113.26    2.00      258.56 

>system.time[1]
Error in system.time[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

If I store the value in a variable, the output of the function doesn't show like I expect:

```
> a <- system.time(lapply(c(1:5000), mean))
> a
user    system  elapsed 
0.02    0.00    0.01
```

Now I can't see the value of mean(c(1:5000)) but the timing is stored like I want. How can I get both the function output and timing value?

Comment: Use `print` around `lapply`?  Or assign the result and then view it. Btw, `lapply(1:5000, mean)` does nothing but return its input.

Comment: Try `b<-system.time(a <- lapply(c(1:5000), mean)); print(a)`

Comment: Use the normal extraction method `a[1]`. Simple typographical error

Comment: a is the value of system.time but the value of mean(1:5000) doesn't show

Comment: `pt <- proc.time(); mean(runif(1000000,1,2)); proc.time() - pt`

Comment: `b<-system.time(a <- lapply(c(1:5000), mean)); print(a)` works well, except I made a mistake and lapply is not the function I wanted, but the concept I was looking for is answered. Thanks

Comment: `pt <- proc.time(); mean(runif(1000000,1,2)); proc.time() - pt` works too thanks.